# Prevent loading every .js files when using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am new to this webpack tool.

I have found this pretty useful but it was quite different from what I have seen from other tools

I am used to having one to one relationship between html and js often named as controller.

However, it looks like webpack just link all the js files (given that we have multiple entry files) to the html without developers to specify which one to link explicitly.

I was wondering if why webpack does this and if there is a way to achieve what I want (loading specific js compiled file for different html files)
example would help a lot!

Comment: My understanding of webpack is that you give it an entry file, or entry files.  It then, as part of its compilation process, knows which other resources those files `require()` or import.  Only those files should be included in the resulting packaged js file(s).

Comment: ya but every entry js files are added to scripts tag. I want html A to include js A and html B to include js B.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [plugin](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-plugin/) that does it:

```
const fs = require("fs");

class FooPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        // This hook fires just before droping all the bundles to dist folder.
        compiler.hooks.emit.tap('FooPlugin', (compilation) => {
            // Get the entry point chunk name. (including its hash and .js suffix).
            const getChunkFullName = (entryPoint) => {
                getChunk(compilation, entryPoint)[0].match(/(.*)\.([^(\.js)]*)\.js$/).fullName;
            }
            
            // For all entry points, create .html and inject the script tag to it.
            entryPoints.forEach((entryPoint => {
                const scriptTag = `<script src="${getChunkFullName(entryPoint)}"></script>`;

                fs.writeFile(entryPoint + ".js", `<html><body>${scriptTag}</body></html>`);
            }))

            return true;
        });
    }
}

module.exports = FooPlugin;
```

Then simply use it in your webpack config:

```
plugins: [FooPlugin]
```